# Code First Context Conditions

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

```
 public class Article
{
    public List<Category> _ArticleCategory;

    public Article()
    {
        _ArticleCategory = new List<Category>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Viewed { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }


}
```

`// I want to take Articles which has more than 1 Category
var result = _context.Articles.Where(a => a.Categories.Count > 1).ToList();`

There is my Article Class and my code to take Articles.There i no problem from _Context or somewhere else. It is giving me all Articles.
How can i make conditions for that ? 
Thanks Guys..

Comment: The query looks ok. Are you sure you have articles with less than 2 categories in your database?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah,I am sure about that.I watched the query from SQL Server Profiler,The  Query doesn't have any conditions,so it returned me all Articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx everybody..
I solved the proplem..

```
public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

//this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
I should open this property when ı want to use virtual list options.Thanx again..  Happy Coding :)